# referencing figures and equations in LaTeX (overleaf) stopped working

Tags: reference, latex, sharelatex

I am writing a report in Overleaf and to my surprise, suddenly all the references stopped working...

Code example:

```
\begin{equation}
        A = B * C
        \label{eq:tryout}
    \end{equation}

Tryout reference: \ref{eq:tryout}
```

The document shows this:

[image]

Does anyone see a syntactical error? Or could it be that I accidentally removed a package or something? Thanks in advance!

p.s. compiling multiple times does not work either

Comment: Can you please  add a [mre] or share the link to your overleaf project?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what the problem was. I was using another package:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Apparently, this package interferes with the standard references, because if I remove it, the document works perfectly again.

Comment: If correctly used `hyperref` does not interfere with the standard references. If you would show us a short example that reproduces the problem, I'm sure we tell you what the problem is.